# Can't import iOS native files from dependent library which depends on another react native library by cocoapods

Tags: react-native

There are tow react library 'A' and library 'B' now. 'A' depends on 'B' and 'B' has iOS native code. After I add library 'A' into my project by yarn and run 'pod install' script. I found 'B's native code hasn't been imported into my project's pods directory. And React Native reports error 'Native module cannot be null'. So, how do I import library 'A' into my project properly? (I can edit library 'A' and 'B')